# Python telnetlib lengthy write command

Tags: python-3.x, telnetlib

I want to write lengthy write command by `telentlib`, but it is limited to only 50 characters. Is the some way to make it longer?

```py
tn.write(('ftp server name "remotehost" address 10.10.10.10 servertype FTP user ftpuser password password').encode())
```

Comment: Why not break it into separate commands?

Comment: The target machine takes this command in one time, so i can't segment it